# Which one is better to iterate through each entry in HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have two ways we can iterate through each entry in hashmap, can you explain which one is to be preferred over other and why ?

```
HashMap m = new HashMap();
m.put("A",100);
m.put("B",100);
m.put("C",100);
m.put("D",100);
```

One way to iterate

```
Set s1 = m.entrySet();
Iterator itr = s1.iterate();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
Map.Entry m1 = (Map.Entry)s1.next();
System.out.println(m1.getKey()+"..."+m1.getValue);
}
```

Second Way to iterate

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> s1 = m.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> m1:s1){
System.out.println(m1.getKey()+"..."+m1.getValue); 
}
```

Comment: I prefer the second one. It gives you type safely etc. But I have no proof etc that it performs better etc.

Comment: please correct the code of the first way so that the difference concentrate to the main aspect 
for example:

`for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> itr = m.entrySet().iterator();itr.hasNext();) {`

`Map.Entry elem = itr.next();`

`System.out.println(elem.getKey() + "..." + elem.getValue());`

`}`

Answer (score 3):

The two are essentially the same (except of the raw types in the first snippet - if you use explicit `Iterator`, there's no reason to use raw `Set`, `Iterator` and `Map.Entry` - use `Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>`, `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>` and `Map.Entry<String,Integer>`).

The enhanced for loop creates an `Iterator` behind the scenes.

However, if you wish to remove elements from the `Set` while iterating over it, you must use an explicit `Iterator` (and that `Iterator`'s `remove()` method).

In addition, in the first snippet you can combine the first two statements - `Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> itr = m.entrySet().iterator();` - since you don't need the `Set` reference.

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: for a simpler comparison of the real differences I rewrote the code*

if you want just work on the elements forgetting that they belongs to a container... the **second way** is better because more concise and clearer to read

```
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> elem : m.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(elem.getKey() + "..." + elem.getValue()); 
}
```

but, if you need to operate on the container structure itself (e.g., add, delete elements)...  the **first way** is the correct one

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> itr = m.entrySet().iterator(); 
     itr.hasNext();) { 
  Map.Entry<String, Integer> elem = itr.next(); 
  System.out.println(elem.getKey() + "..." + elem.getValue());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They're equivalent, so I would definitely prefer the second, because it's simpler, and a little bit faster (although it will probably be hard to notice).

I'd simplify it even further though:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> m1 : s1.entrySet()){
  System.out.println(m1.getKey() + "..." + m1.getValue); 
}
```